# Lists Definition, View toolbar type = none

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, custom-list, ribbon

in my list schema definition, in the allItems view I added the element:

```
<Toolbar Type="None" />
```

But I still see the toolbar in the view page. (I can add list items, and new views).

 I would like to remove the bar. How can I do it?

Thanks,Nk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the attribute  ToolbarTemplate="None" in the View element

```
<View BaseViewID="1" ... ToolbarTemplate="None" ...
```

Comment: The bar is still there but it is disabled. Great :)